# Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) in Angular2 application

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am new to angularjs and developed a demo application using angular2.
    I get the following error while running the application. Although the below error says 404, when i hit the same url (ie http://localhost:4679/Binder/CustomerModuleLibrary) on the browser with the extension .js , the script does get loaded into the browser.

```
Here is the error:

Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:4679/Binder/CustomerModuleLibrary
        at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as _onreadystatechange] (http://localhost:4679/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:698:29)
        at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4679/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:265:35)
        at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:4679/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:154:47)
        at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:4679/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:335:33)
    Error loading http://localhost:4679/Binder/CustomerModuleLibrary as "./CustomerModuleLibrary" from http://localhost:4679/UI/startup/../../Binder/Startup.js
```

Code for CustomerModuleLibrary.ts

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {CustomerComponent} from './CustomerComponent';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms'

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule,FormsModule],
    declarations: [CustomerComponent],
    bootstrap: [CustomerComponent]
})
export class CustomerModuleLibrary { }
```

Code for Startup.ts

```
import {platformBrowserDynamic} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {CustomerModuleLibrary} from './CustomerModuleLibrary';
const platform = platformBrowserDynamic();
platform.bootstrapModule(CustomerModuleLibrary);
```

In the systemjs.config.js file,

```
packages: {
app: {
    main: '../../Binder/Startup.js',
defaultExtension: 'js'
}, 
rxjs: {
defaultExtension: 'js'
},
```

Also, Should i perform npm start before running the application?

Comment: the problem is with incorrect configuration of `system.config.js`, show your full directory structure

Comment: AngularProject has 3 folders 1. Binder 1a. CustomerComponent.ts 1b.CustomerModuleLibrary.ts 1c.Statuup.ts 2.Model 2a.Customer.ts  3.UI 3a. Customet.html 3b.Master.html 4.System.config.js

Comment: I can help you if you create either a plunker or github repo with your project setup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed adding this in master.html. Adding this solved the issue.

```
System.config({
       "defaultJSExtensions":true
    });
```